# AR Application suddenly keeps on crashing

Tags: android, arcore

I'm currently working on an application. I'm trying to figure out what causes of my project keeps crashing. The first try I'm doing this 
 [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xkZUPUbgoM&lc=z225izwiwpeohxege04t1aokgmmfot43nvvcdmlfbiw1bk0h00410.1560938023284194), it successfully works but the second time I have tried the tutorial again, I could not open the application and it keeps on crashing then after that, the first try of the tutorial that I have made also suddenly keeps crashing. I don't know if my project itself has the problem or the emulator I have been using is the problem because when I open the other AR application, I could not open any of it and it keeps on crashing as well. Do you guys have any solution for this or someone encountered this problem? Thanks

These are the red text in the log cat

```
2019-06-21 10:04:27.030 26365-26384/com.example.myapplication E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008a30
2019-06-21 10:04:27.030 26365-26384/com.example.myapplication E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008a30
2019-06-21 10:04:27.901 26365-26365/com.example.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-06-21 10:04:27.929 26365-26365/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 26365
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class ImageViewz
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class ImageViewz
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class ImageViewz
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.ImageViewz" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-6azmPYNrU5Dxd_kmJU2wIg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-6azmPYNrU5Dxd_kmJU2wIg==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myapplication-6azmPYNrU5Dxd_kmJU2wIg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:703)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

activity_main.xml

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.ar.core.Anchor;
import com.google.ar.core.HitResult;
import com.google.ar.core.Plane;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ViewRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ArFragment arFragment;
    private ModelRenderable bearRenderable,
            catRenderable,
                            cowRenderable,
                            dogRenderable,
                            elephantRenderable,
                            ferretRenderable,
                            hippopotamusRenderable,
                            horseRenderable,
                            koala_bearRenderable,
                            lionRenderable,
                            reindeerRenderable,
                            wolverineRenderable;

    ImageView bear,cat,cow,dog,elephant,ferret,hippo,horse,koala,lion,reindeer, wolverine;
    View arrayView[];
    ViewRenderable name_animal;

    int selected = 1;



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arFragment = (ArFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sceneform_ux_fragment);

        bear = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bear);
        cat = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cat);
        cow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cow);
        dog = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dog);
        elephant = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.elephant);
        ferret = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ferret);
        hippo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hippopotamus);
        horse = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.horse);
        koala = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.koala_bear);
        lion = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lion);
        reindeer = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.reindeer);
        wolverine = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wolverine);

        setArrayView();
        setClickListener();

        setupModel();



        arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) -> {

            Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
            AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
            anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

            createModel(anchorNode,selected);

        });
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void setupModel() {

        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.bear)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> bearRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load bear model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );

        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.cat)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> catRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load cat model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );

        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.cow)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> cowRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load cow model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.dog)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> dogRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load dog model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.elephant)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> elephantRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load elephant model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.ferret)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> ferretRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load ferret model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.hippopotamus)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> hippopotamusRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load hippopotamus model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );

        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.horse)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> horseRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load horse model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );

        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.koala_bear)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> koala_bearRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load koala bear model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.lion)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> lionRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load lion model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );

        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.reindeer)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> reindeerRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load reindeer model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );

        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this,R.raw.wolverine)
                .build().thenAccept(renderable -> wolverineRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable ->{
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to load wolverine model",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );




    }

    private void createModel(AnchorNode anchorNode, int selected) {
    if(selected == 1){
        TransformableNode bear = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());



        bear.setParent(anchorNode);
        bear.setRenderable(bearRenderable);
        bear.select();

    }

    if(selected == 2){
            TransformableNode cat = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());



            cat.setParent(anchorNode);
            cat.setRenderable(catRenderable);
            cat.select();
        }

        if(selected == 3){
            TransformableNode cow = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());



            cow.setParent(anchorNode);
            cow.setRenderable(cowRenderable);
            cow.select();
        }

        if(selected == 4){
            TransformableNode dog = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());



            dog.setParent(anchorNode);
            dog.setRenderable(dogRenderable);
            dog.select();
        }

        if(selected == 5){
            TransformableNode elephant = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());



            elephant.setParent(anchorNode);
            elephant.setRenderable(elephantRenderable);
            elephant.select();
        }

        if(selected == 6){
            TransformableNode ferret = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());


            ferret.setParent(anchorNode);
            ferret.setRenderable(ferretRenderable);
            ferret.select();
        }

        if(selected == 7){
            TransformableNode hippopotamus = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());



            hippopotamus.setParent(anchorNode);
            hippopotamus.setRenderable(hippopotamusRenderable);
            hippopotamus.select();
        }

        if(selected == 8){
            TransformableNode horse = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());



            horse.setParent(anchorNode);
            horse.setRenderable(horseRenderable);
            horse.select();
        }

        if(selected == 9){
            TransformableNode koala_bear = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());



            koala_bear.setParent(anchorNode);
            koala_bear.setRenderable(koala_bearRenderable);
            koala_bear.select();
        }

        if(selected == 10){
            TransformableNode lion = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());



            lion.setParent(anchorNode);
            lion.setRenderable(lionRenderable);
            lion.select();
        }

        if(selected == 11){
            TransformableNode reindeer = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());



            reindeer.setParent(anchorNode);
            reindeer.setRenderable(reindeerRenderable);
            reindeer.select();
        }

        if(selected == 12){
            TransformableNode wolverine = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());



            wolverine.setParent(anchorNode);
            wolverine.setRenderable(wolverineRenderable);
            wolverine.select();
        }
    }

    private void setArrayView(){
        arrayView = new View[]{
                bear,cat,cow,dog,elephant,ferret,hippo,horse,koala,lion,reindeer, wolverine
        };
    }

    private void setClickListener(){
        for(int i=0; i<arrayView.length;i++) {
            arrayView[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

MainActivity.Java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment

        android:id="@+id/sceneform_ux_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bear"
                android:src="@drawable/bear"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cat"
                android:src="@drawable/cat"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dog"
                android:src="@drawable/dog"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cow"
                android:src="@drawable/cow"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/elephant"
                android:src="@drawable/elephant"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ferret"
                android:src="@drawable/ferret"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/hippopotamus"
                android:src="@drawable/hippopotamus"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/horse"
                android:src="@drawable/horse"/>

            <ImageViewz
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/koala_bear"
                android:src="@drawable/koala_bear"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lion"
                android:src="@drawable/lion"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/reindeer"
                android:src="@drawable/reindeer"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/wolverine"
                android:src="@drawable/wolverine"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Latest Logcat

```
2019-06-21 10:44:17.018 27155-27155/com.example.myapplication I/native: session.cc:850 Entering Session::Resume.
2019-06-21 10:44:17.021 27155-27155/com.example.myapplication I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
2019-06-21 10:44:17.028 27155-27155/com.example.myapplication I/native: android_sensors.cc:139 Starting thread.
2019-06-21 10:44:17.029 27155-27155/com.example.myapplication I/native: cameras.cc:542 Selected camera 0 stream 0 as feature extraction stream.
2019-06-21 10:44:17.029 27155-27155/com.example.myapplication E/NdkImageReader: AImageReader_getWindow
2019-06-21 10:44:17.031 27155-27198/com.example.myapplication I/native: android_sensors.cc:28 Gyro min delay 10ms requesting 10ms
2019-06-21 10:44:17.038 27155-27198/com.example.myapplication I/native: android_sensors.cc:28 Accel min delay 10ms requesting 10ms
2019-06-21 10:44:17.092 27155-27155/com.example.myapplication E/ACameraManager: openCamera: connect camera device failed: Status(-8): '10: connectHelper:1399: Failed to initialize camera "0": Function not implemented (-38)'
2019-06-21 10:44:17.094 27155-27155/com.example.myapplication E/native: android_camera.cc:529 Reset: Resetting camera 0 from an ERROR state, best effort clean-up commencing
2019-06-21 10:44:17.111 27155-27155/com.example.myapplication W/native: session.cc:905 Session::Resume returning generic::unknown: ACameraManager_openCamera.
2019-06-21 10:44:17.111 27155-27155/com.example.myapplication E/native: status.cc:153 generic::unknown: ACameraManager_openCamera
2019-06-21 10:44:17.119 27155-27155/com.example.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-06-21 10:44:17.124 27155-27155/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 27155
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3581)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2862)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException
        at com.google.ar.core.au.a(Session.java:2)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.throwExceptionFromArStatus(Session.java:105)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.nativeResume(Native Method)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.resume(Session.java:45)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.resume(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.start(BaseArFragment.java:453)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.onResume(BaseArFragment.java:299)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2498)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:3241)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:223)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:538)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:527)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:172)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2862) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your xml code.

Try using:

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/koala_bear"
                android:src="@drawable/koala_bear"/>
```

instead of:

```
<ImageViewz
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/koala_bear"
                android:src="@drawable/koala_bear"/>
```

Comment: The application still keep crashing

Comment: Then it must be due to another error. Can you post the latest log file?

Comment: What is the API level of device you are running your app on?

Comment: I'm currently using API 27 but I'm also using API 28 and it keeps on crashing. I don't know if the AVD is the problem or the android studio is the problem.